# GWT Best Practices - MVP

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

A question for all the GWT gurus out there.

I'm a newbie in GWT and am trying to understand the best practices of coding a GWT application. I have gone through ["Large scale application development and MVP"](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) based on Ray Ryan's talk at Google I/O 2009 and it has given me a good starting point. I downloaded the sample source code as well for the Contacts application based on the best practices listed.

The application I'm trying to develop using GWT is a bit bigger (in terms of the modules involved) when compared to the sample "Contacts" application & so I want to split it up into multiple functions.

I have been reading that having a single Entry point in a GWT application is a good idea, and I don't want to dump all the code in one single AppController class & one single RpcService, what would be the best approach in this situation?

How would I go about dispatching the control to multiple controllers? Is there a way to achieve this using some classes in the GWT framework?

Comment: I wasn't a 100 % clear in my mind about what I wanted when I posted this question. I think after further reading, I have found what I wanted - The GWT best practices implementation along with a bunch of other things that I need to do @ 

1. http://blog.hivedevelopment.co.uk/2009/08/integerating-gwt-dispatch-with-jboss.html

2. http://peterkenji.blogspot.com/2009/09/getting-gwt-spring-dispatch-library.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For large GWT apps, a framework like [GWTP](https://github.com/arcbees/gwtp) (which is a fork of [gwt-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/) and [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/)) is almost necessary. It provides things like Places for handling location/history, a handy Presenter framework, EventBus, and really simple codesplitting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing very big application then split your application into multiple modules.
For client side MVC pattern I suggest PureMVC.

http://puremvc.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about initial load size and it's possible to load your big app in different chunks, consider [Code Splitting](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html)